# How to determine the reason of low performance of a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` as my main view of my application. The contents of this `UITableView` is loaded from web via HTTP request as JSON, 5 item at a time. There is no performance issues with this request part.

After that, cells are generated programmatically according to JSON data's content. For example if JSON says a cell contains 1 `UILabel`, 1 `UITextField` and 1 `UIButton`. I add these as subviews to correct `UITableViewCell`. Initial state of the cells have no issues either.

As you scroll down, new items are loaded from web, and this is the method triggers "load more" functionality.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let lastElement = data.jsonArray.count - 2
    if indexPath.row == lastElement {
        page += 1
        getFeed()
    }
}
```

However, as you scroll down you can notice small freezes and lags and this looks very bad. I have no idea why these small freezes occur.

This is how it looks right now. I recorded this on emulator, but on a real device it is much worse.

I don't know what should I do here. Any advices? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code in `cellForAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: It is very long and complex.

Comment: `getFeed` will call multiple time when user scroll at last index often. you should prevent to call method if it's already being executing.

Comment: OK ! You can find the things cause bad performance by this way: Remove all business code in `cell forRowAtIndexPath:`, and review the performance again. If the performance still bad, it's because the cornerRadius, gradient, autolayout, ... problem. Otherwise, the problem is because of you business code hold main thread too long. You can un-comment code line by line until you found the problem !

Comment: It seems adding views to cells cause the performance issues. I currently remove all subviews from cell at the start of cellforRowAtIndexPath, then add them. Is it a bad method of doing it ?

Comment: You can determine the low performance of your code by using Profiling tools available in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

- As you fetching data from server for each cell it will always lag.For
  making the experience smoother you need fetch 10-15 JSON object in
  advance & store them in the array. Whenever you make new request add
  those objects in the array.
- So you will not make service request for each cell instead you make
  request after  10-15 cell(you can increase this count if your json
  object contains less fields). You can show spinner at bottom when
  make new request.
- For this also need to make mechanism at server side to give you
  object in array of 10-15

This mechanism is also known as **Pagination**.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ( (indexPath.row == array.count - 1)) {
        // This is the last cell
        [self loadMore];
    }
}

// Load more
- (void)loadMore {

     //make service request for next page (Make sure your response contains next 10 objects)
     //on response add those objects in the array
     //reload table view
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear, I actually fetch 5 items at a time.

Comment: you can set this approach on 5 objects too.Please edit your question for better clearity

Comment: I removed all views from my cell, only left pagination methods. It seems they work fine and does not affect performance. The problem is how views are added to cells probably.

Comment: It is very long method, but at the start of it, I remove all views from cell, then start to add them again.

Comment: It means you are allocating new views Each time & not get advantage of dequeuing feature.That what dequeue does is to save from allocation of new object each time.

Comment: How do I do that with non-static structure of my cells?